Find an example of connected topology for finite space $\{1,...,n\}$ that conforms with the intuition of a commoner.
The most common topology for finite space is the discrete topology, which is clearly not connected.
There are some other discussion on this site, which give many example topology of finite space and $\mathbb N$, most if not all of them are not connected.
We want to find an example of non-trivial connected topology for finite space $\{1,...,n\}$, and it would be naturally separable and second countable..
My try: clearly a $T_4$ connected topological space is uncountable. So we are looking for a topology $T_3$ or below.
One example for $\mathbb N$ is the Golomb space, the "prime number topology". Of course, these types of topology are not trivial and meet many requirements. However, I think it is a bit hard to understand for commoners, and it does not work for finite space.

Related: https://www.math.columbia.edu/department/lipshitz/teaching/CladerThesis.pdf

You can just take the indiscrete topology. More interesting choices are possible which have interesting homotopy theory, see e.g.: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-22003-6

For finite spaces, any $T_1$ topology is automatically discrete, so at most you can get $T_0$.

Apart from indiscrete topology, another choice would be included point topology, that is, a set is open iff it is either empty or contains a specific point (say $1$), or excluded point topology, that is, a set is open iff it is the full space or excludes a specific point (say $1$).

@QiaochuYuan Yes I think the latter one you suggested is both intuitive and non-trivial, of course. I am looking for an example of this.

Here is a list of finite connected $T_0$ spaces. https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Finite%2BConnected%2B%24T_0%24
I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "intuition of a commoner" but perhaps an example that relates to an ordered finite set is the ray topology: a set is open provided for each point of the set, every point greater than it also belongs to the set.

Very useful website!
